# Can we do Weierstrass factorization for trigonometric substitutions? If so, in which cases?

Tags: trigonometry, reference-request, soft-question, fourier-analysis, weierstrass-factorization

We have in complex analysis the famous [Weierstrass factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) which says that every entire function can be written

$$f(z) = z^ne^{g(z)}\prod_{k=0}^\infty E_{p_n} \left(\frac{z}{a_n}\right)$$

Now to the question, what happens if we do $z=\sin(w)$ or maybe $z = \exp(iw)$?

Will this still be able to represent something useful?

Comment: Are you seeking to invert such conditions to the form $w=f(z)$? Neither $\sin w$ nor $\exp iw$ is invertible.

Comment: @J.G. You are right, maybe I should have restricted the domain. Or considered periodic functions.